# Swift 4: unrecognized selector sent to instance ERROR

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with UILocalizedIndexedCollation in swift 4 and I keep getting the following error:

> Exception: -[_SwiftValue localizedTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000024cc00
>   2018-01-06 21:11:14.148103-0500 TableViewContacts[27012:2886540] [Contacts] Error communicating with XPC Service: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4101 "connection to service named com.apple.contactsd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.contactsd}

Im simply trying to fetch my contacts using the contacts framework and displaying it on the tableview.

This my following code for my collation:

```
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()
    var sections: [[AnyObject]] = []
    var objects: [Contact] = [] {
        didSet {
            let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: UIApplicationShortcutItem.localizedTitle)
            sections = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)

            let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArray(from: objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for object in sortedObjects {
                let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object as AnyObject)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as fetching my contacts:

```
private func fetchContacts(){

    let store = CNContactStore()

    store.requestAccess(for: (.contacts)) { (granted, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print("Failed to request access",err)
            return
        }

        if granted {
            print("Access granted")
            let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
            let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

            fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault

            do {
                try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { ( contact, error) -> Void in
                    self.objects.append(Contact(contact: contact))
                })



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }


        }else{
            print("Access denied")
        }
    }

    }
```

I Believe the problem is the selector. I knwo for swift 4 we use the @objc when we declare a function and use it as a selector. But in this case, I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Add exception breakpoint and rerun.

Comment: did you ever solve this, I am facing the same erro

Answer (score 1):

Yep, your selector is wrong. Here's what I ended up doing to get the selector to work.

```
var objects: [CollationIndexable] = [] {
        didSet {
            sections = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)
            let selector = #selector(getter: CollationIndexable.collationString)

            let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArray(from: objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for object in sortedObjects {
                let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object as AnyObject)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Here is my protocol that your objects should implement

```
@objc protocol CollationIndexable {
    @objc var collationString : String { get }
}
```

And here is an example of a concrete CollationIndexable type implementing protocol and selector property

```
extension Contact : CollationIndexable {

    @objc var collationString : String {
        return lastName
    }
}
```